# How to manipulate JSON Array for QTable

Tags: vuejs2, quasar-framework

if the below array is used as data for Qtable

```
user = { fname: "mike", lname : "duke", age : 35, hobby :"swimming"}
```

we will get,

| fname | lname | age |  hobby   |

| mike  | duke  | 35  | swimming |

[image: screenshot]

Q1. how can I manipulate the user array and/or Qtable property to makes it into

| keys  | values  |

| fname | mike    |

| lname | duke    |

| age   |    35   |

|hobby  |swimming |

[image: screenshot]

*The user array would be dynamically loaded from API and content varies,*

Q2. is there any other quasar components for viewing/listing this as shown above?

Answer (score 0):

```
<q-table .... :data="userData" ..... />

.
.
.
computed: {
  userdata () {
    return Object.entries(this.user).map(([k,v]) => { return { key: k, value: v}})
}
}
```

Rob, on quasar framework forum.